# Prove $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ using determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here's the question:

> Show that if $A^2$ is the zero matrix, then the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$.

Here was my idea: if $A^2$ is the zero matrix, then $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2=0$, thus $\det(A)=0$ and $A$ is not invertible. Thus $0$ can be the only eigenvalue of $A$.

Does this hold?

Comment: The proof you proposed is wrong. $\det A=0$ implies that *at least* one eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$, but $A$ may very well have others. For instance, the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix (or of a triangular one) are precisely the diagonal entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that a matrix can have zero determinant and still have non-zero eigenvalues. For instance if
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} $$
then $\det(A)=0$, but $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Instead, suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, i.e. that $Av=\lambda v$ for some (non-zero) vector $v$. What happens if you apply $A$ again?

Answer (score 4):

If $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x \ne 0$ and if $A^2=0$, then
$$
       0= A^2x= \lambda^2 x \implies \lambda = 0.
$$

Comment: What about if done without the square? Actually what do you want to proof? That if A^2 is the 0 matrix then all eigen value of A is 0?

Comment: @user21795 : I showed what was in the yellow box of the question. That is, if $A^2$ is the $0$ matrix, then the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^2$, so the roots are a subset of the roots of $p(x)=x^2$, of which there is just one, namely $0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't hold. Consider for example the matrix which has it's first entry 1 and all the other entries zero. Then it's eigenvalues are 0 and 1 but it is not invertible.